# Erro de tipo no método de Classe, [Ignora o this e fala que o método não existe]

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Bom dia, estou enfrentando um probleminha, ao chamar via rota do express um método da classe **ControllerContact** ele diz que o método não existe.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
require('dotenv').config();

class ControllerContact{
    index(req,res){
        if(this.formatData(req.body.name,req.body.email,req.body.message)){
            res.json({code:200,text:'sucessfull'});
        }else{
            res.json({code:500,text:'Error'});
        }
    }

    formatData(name,email){
        this.sendMail(email,require('./views/thanks')({name,email})).catch(console.error);
        this.sendMail(email,require('./views/forMe')({name,email,message:'enviado'})).catch(console.error);
        return true;
    }

    async sendMail(mail,message){
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
            port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
            secure: process.SMTP_SECURITY,
            auth: {
              user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
              pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD
            },
        });

        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: '"'+process.env.SMTP_NAME+'" <response@email.com>',
            to: mail,
            subject: message[2],
            text: message[0],
            html: message[1],
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new ControllerContact();
```

O erro que aparece para mim é o seguinte (Vindo da requisição):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatData' of undefined
    at index (/Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/src/contact/controller.js:6:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/erick/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/usuario/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/usuario/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/Users/usuario/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/portifolio/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Estou usando JS Comum não Typescript

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir esse problema... Para mim (até mesmo no console do navegador – removendo variáveis desnecessárias para execução mínima) o código chegou a executar o método `formatData`.

Comment: Também não consegui reproduzir o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Presumo que na sua rota esteja declarado:

```
Route.post('controller', ControllerContact.index)
```

Acontece que quando você passa o método `index` para o callback da função `Route` ele perde o contexto, logo o this passa a ser undefined.

Tente fazer isso:

```
Route.post('controller', () => ControllerContact.index())
```

Observe que o `index` continua atrelado a classe em que foi declarado

Espero ter ajudado!